# Missing credits for answer 

Tags: support, status-bydesign, daily-reputation-limit

This answer:

[Recursive Descent Parser for something simple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531947/recursive-descent-parser-for-something-simple/5544100#5544100)

For every other question with positive votes in the past, I've seen what I think are appropriate credits.  This one shows 2 votes, but shows as line with "blank" for points in [my reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter?tab=reputation).
Is there a significant time delay? (I haven't seen delays of more than a few minutes in the past). What don't I understand? (I'm assuming it isn't a bug, but I could only tag with "bug". Sorry.).

EDIT: Maybe I hit a daily reputation cap? (Hasn't happened before, so I don't know how to recognize it).  If so, it isn't labelled very well.

Comment: I think it did happen before, as you have the **Mortarboard** badge from before today!  Though I did look through your rep history and can't see where it would have been awarded.  Strange...

Comment: So I think this issue is resolved.  I tried to change the tag from "bug" to something else like "resolved"... but there isn't any such tag.  In fact, when I removed "bug" (leaving "reputation-limit" as the only tag, I got a complaint: "Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted: "•must include one of these tags -- 'bug feature-request discussion support".   None seems right.  I have chosen "discussion" as the last worst but that seems to leave this open as some kind of problem, which it is not.  How do I mark this in meta as uninteresting?   I'd be happy to delete it, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: only moderator can change to red tag (status-[x] faq etc) so you can Flag your own post asking for their divine intervention. (Not needed here anymore thanks to mmyers :)) Regarding deletion, same thing - once your question got answers you can't delete it yourself, only moderator can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hit the daily rep limit of 200, so any further upvotes won't raise your reputation.

Probably the votes were cast after your rep limit was reached so you don't see this in the log as it really didn't have any effect on your repuation.

Comment: Ah, I had just guessed that.