# I'm not getting reputation from all votes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-graph

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Missing credits for answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85941/missing-credits-for-answer) 
>   [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it)
>   [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I am seeing something a little odd in my Stack Overflow reputation, specifically on question [If Java's garbage collector moves objects, what is Object.hashCode and System.identityHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207302/if-javas-garbage-collector-moves-objects-what-is-object-hashcode-and-system-ide/7207394#7207394). I have 7 up-votes and an accepted answer, but my reputation graph for today only shows 20 points for up-votes and 15 for the accepted answer.

What's up? Is there a better way to report this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have already exceeded your reputation limit for today (200 reputation from question and answer votes) after the first two upvotes. Any remaining votes today don't give you any reputation.

However, you can still earn reputation above the limit for accepted answers and bounties.